# Display Message on top right via jQuery + CSS

Tags: jquery, css

[image]

I don't want to include extra library for a small alert message.
I want to dynamically **append** one to the DOM when need one and will **fadeOut** in 3s, and will **remove** from the DOM after.

I've tried codes below, but I have no luck and see nothing display.

```
$('body').append('<div id="msg" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background:green; color:red;  z-index: 999; "> copied ! </div>');
$("#msg").fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $("#msg").delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
});
$("#msg").remove();
```

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Can we make sure, its z-index is the highest, so it won't cover under modal or other element ?

Comment: `$("#msg").remove();` you need to do this at the end of the fadeOut. The current code will just remove #msg as soon as it runs

Comment: @Huangism, so I can chain it. nice. will do.

Comment: @cyber8200 not chain it, there is a onComplete callback to fadeOut, you just put the removal in the onComplete function https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/ here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/dwg4pvmq/

Comment: Check my answer @cyber8200

Answer (score 1):

Your msg is being removed without a delay. As for the `z-index`, the maximum range is ±2147483647. Hope this helps:

```
$('body').append('<div id="msg" style="position: fixed; padding: 50px; top: 20px; left: 20px; background:green; color:red;  z-index: 9999; "> copied ! </div>');
$("#msg").fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $("#msg").delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', () => {$("#msg").remove()});
});
```

Comment: What is `() =>` ?

Comment: lambda function. Just a lazy way to run a block of code via an anonymous function :). By the way, you can ensure that the `z-index` is the highest by using the css `!important` after declaring your `z-index`;

Comment: ECMA 6, same as `function() {}`

Comment: Not working.. :( 

I have settings triggering by modal, and my modal have bg color as black. I have a feeling that the success message triggered, but it cover by my modal that have black bg opacity 1.

Comment: remove the removal code, trigger the message and inspect your dom

Comment: Your codes seems to have same effect as the code I posted

Comment: hmmm if you run it in the console, it works for me. try it yourself by doing ctrl  + shift + j

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dwg4pvmq/ it's basically the same as above except no ECMA 6

Comment: What is it different between your codes and mine ? I want to learn from it.

Comment: Basically, the removal of the message is delayed by 3000ms + the amount of time it takes for the fade animation

Comment: Your explanation should be in your answer. :)

Comment: It the z-index, issue. it display now; I increase it to : `9999`

Comment: @isherwood is it is : "Your msg is being removed without a delay"

Comment: @cyber8200, Oh ok, nice

Answer (score 1):

`fadeIn` takes a `callback` function. As a result, it'll work asynchronously. In the mean time, later portion of code `$("#msg").remove()` will be executed. So, to achieve your goal code like below.

Try:

```
$('body').append('<div id="msg" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; background:green; color:red;  z-index: 999; "> copied ! </div>');

$("#msg").fadeIn('slow', function () {
    $("#msg").delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', () => $("#msg").remove());
});
```